# RDS instance in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, private-subnet

Given a VPC, can I not explicitly mention which subnets the RDS instance should exist?

I have created a VPC `10.0.0.0/24` with three subnets as shown below:

- REST servers - `10.0.0.0/25`
- RDS - AZ1 - `10.0.0.128/26`
- RDS - AZ2 - `10.0.0.192/26`

When creating the DB, I am able to provide the VPC name. It seems, all subnets of this VPC are automatically selected. I am not able to specify the two subnets (as shown in the list above). There is an option for public accessibility which I have set to No. Therefore, even though all subnets seem to be applied for this RDS instance, it seems that, it will be accessible only from the REST servers subnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the DBSubnet Group , which should have your private subnets.

Comment: It lists the public one too. The subnet for REST servers has a route with internet gateway.

Comment: you need to create DBSubnet group, put your private subnets there, and then select that DBSubnet group while launching the RDS

Comment: Yes; got it working after creating the DB subnet group.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new subnet group and assign it while creating a new RDS. Make note that existing RDS doesn't reflect when you change the subnet group, hence you need to create a new one.

Comment: So I cannot create subnets in advance and then use them when defining RDS.

Comment: you can create a new db subnet group with specific subnets, then while creating a new instance make sure to select that particular subnet group.

Answer (score 0):

Before you create your Database Instance you need to select the option "Subnet groups" inside the RDS page. There you can select your VPC then one or more subnet. After that, go to "Create Database", select the VPC and you'll be able to select your "subnet group" that was created earlier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).